# Does Apple restrict email as mandatory field in Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I want to create an iOS app and use **Facebook Login** and it will also have other way to **Login with email**. I thought of keeping email-id field mandatory and unique so that users can be identified uniquely irrespective of the way of login!

Apple keep all the apps in serious consideration so does apple restrict this mandatory field of email in Facebook Login?

Does apple come into picture while communicating to Facebook Server?
Will Apple reject the app if email field is mandatory?

Comment: Not all Facebook users have an email address

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow apps that require you to share person information to work, like an e-mail address.

**See: 17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected**

It also states that your app is asking to create an account to access the full app and even needs the account or access features that do not require the user to have an account. You can make those features available without the account creating you might be able to get through the review.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is featuring only account based functionality that is specific to a user, i don't think you will get rejection on asking users to register via email. Snippet from Apple app review guideline's clause 17.2 -

> "Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app
>   features and content that are not associated specifically to the user.
>   User registration that requires the sharing of personal information
>   must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality.
>   Additionally, the requested information must be relevant to the
>   features."